# Service timed out: Spreadsheets: Why now?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As of the beginning of May, one of my scripts has started to throw a Service timed out: Spreadsheets error.

Nothing in this script has been touched in months so I know it is not down to the code actually being in question, however this seems to take about 20 minutes for the script to time out and the script on a normal day only takes seconds to run!

I have tried doing a debug on the script and seems to timeout on the very first attempt to do a `.getValue()` I have created a new script with a `.getValue()` command and I get the same result so seems to have trouble getting one cell of data???

```py
function ArchiveCopy() { 

    var ss         = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet      = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
    var sheets     = ["DATA","TEAM LEADERS","PRODUCTION IN","PRODUCTION OUT","TOTALS"];

    var getDate    = Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange(5,33).getValue(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var getShift   = sheet.getRange(3,33).getValue();
    var getShift2  = sheet.getRange(7,33).getValue();
    var getNum     = sheet.getRange(11,36).getValue();
    var getDay     = sheet.getRange(6,33).getValue();
    var getNext    = sheet.getRange(11,37).getValue();
    var d = new Date();
    var currentTime = Utilities.formatDate(d, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH")

    if (getDay == "Mon") { Logger.log("Monday"); shiftRota() }
    if ((currentTime == 8) | (currentTime == 16 & getShift != "WEEKEND (DAYS)") | (currentTime == 20 & getShift == "WEEKEND (DAYS)") | (currentTime == 0 & getShift != "WEEKEND (NIGHTS)")){
    ## Code it does not even get to ## }
}
```

The script times out when it reaches the variable getDate. Just to clarrify this script has been running flawlessly for the last 5 months without a single hiccup and started to play up  as the below error code shows

> 4/30/19 1:15 PM    ArchiveCopy Service timed out: Spreadsheets (line 207, file "Data", project "Handover - Functions") time-based  4/30/19 1:36 PM

If this an issue on the Cloud side of things? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: To get values, don't get lots of individual cell ranges.  The rows you are getting are 3 through 15.  There are rows that you aren't getting data from, but it's actually better to get a range once, and get the data once even though lots of that data isn't going to be retrieved.  So, for example, the code isn't getting a value from row 10, and you might think that getting row 10's data along with every thing else would *not* be good, because it's never retrieved, but getting lots of individual cells is worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheet Script problem - Error: Service Times Out: Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302086/google-spreadsheet-script-problem-error-service-times-out-apps-script)

Comment: I have done a test on it, I removed the .getValue() commands in lines 3 to 15 that does not effect the following if statements, and made the if statement that follows completely empty. It still throws this error. I then decided to to remove the if statement completely and the variables and just leave a logger, it took 362 seconds just to tell me a logger message..