# How to fix 'Service timed out: Spreadsheets' error for simple script using clearContent()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple script (please see below) that has been running without problems for months. Since May 4, 2019, it throws a **'Service timed out: Spreadsheets'** error and it appears that the `clearContent()` function is not working as before. Do you have a hint of what the problem could be?

I tried the Google App Scripts debugging mode. Also, when I create a copy of the respective Google Sheet, the script works for some time, before I get the same error again.

```
function clearArea(){    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
  var area1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");    
  area1.getRange("A2:C1000").clearContent();

}
```

> Up until May 4, 2019, the script would just empty the cells A2: C1000.

Please see the execution logs below:

```
[19-05-08 07:22:44:345 PDT] Starting execution
[19-05-08 07:22:44:356 PDT] PropertiesService.getScriptProperties() [0 seconds]
[19-05-08 07:22:44:357 PDT] PropertiesService.getUserProperties() [0 seconds]
[19-05-08 07:22:44:491 PDT] PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties() [0.133 seconds]
[19-05-08 07:22:44:493 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-05-08 07:22:44:569 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sheet 1]) [0.075 seconds]
[19-05-08 07:22:44:570 PDT] Sheet.getRange([A2:C1000]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-08 07:22:44:571 PDT] Range.clearContent() [0 seconds]
[19-05-08 07:26:44:644 PDT] Execution failed: Service timed out: Spreadsheets [0.085 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post and include execution logs so we can see timings for your script steps. To see these, run the script then go to View > Execution transcript.

Answer (score 1):

I think it looks like you are doing a lot of single cell update operations in your scripts. This may be the reason for the random failures you are getting from the Spreadsheets. Take a look at this [guide](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/best-practices#use_batch_operations_when_updating_spreadsheets) that may help you for using batch operations for updating your sheets.

Comment: Thanks. I will follow this guide. As of this morning, the script works fine again without any adjustments. I am also wondering if my problem is related to this one  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981607/service-timed-out-spreadsheets-why-now?rq=) and it was due to any update of Google Sheets/Apps Script over the weekend.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it's related. Kindly accept or upvote if this is helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: So I tried the guide you referred me to, but unfortunately, it did not help. By now, I found another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076628/g-suite-scripts-that-worked-perfectly-2-years-long-do-not-work-anymore) which from my point of view seem to also be related to my problem.