# Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script access a .csv file and parse the data to Google Sheet. This script was working fine till yesterday. Did something change?

```
function ImportOpscenterExportData() {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('<<Folder ID>>'); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('<<Filename.csv>>'); // latest report file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<<Spreadsheet ID>>'); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('<<Sheet Name>>');
  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "Filename.csv" file exists in the reports folder
    var getLastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      sheet.getRange(i+getLastRow, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
      var newgetLastrow = sheet.getRange(i+getLastRow, 1).getValue();
      if (newgetLastrow != "") {
      sheet.getRange(i+getLastRow,10).setValue('=iferror(if(AND(A' + (i+getLastRow) + '="",K' + (i+getLastRow) + '=""),"",if(K' + (i+getLastRow) + '="","No","Yes")),"No")');
      sheet.getRange(i+getLastRow,11).setValue('=iferror(QUERY(rawdata_jira!$A$2:$H,"SELECT B WHERE A CONTAINS """&$A' + (i+getLastRow) + '&""" AND A CONTAINS """&$C' + (i+getLastRow) + '&""" AND A CONTAINS """&$D' + (i+getLastRow) + '&""" AND A CONTAINS """&$E' + (i+getLastRow) + '&""" AND A CONTAINS ""(Error Code: "&$F' + (i+getLastRow) + '&")"" ",0),"")');
      sheet.getRange(i+getLastRow,12).setValue('=IFERROR(INDEX(rawdata_jira!$F:$F,MATCH($K' + (i+getLastRow) + ',rawdata_jira!$B:$B,0)),"")');
      sheet.getRange(i+getLastRow,14).setValue('=IF(A' + (i+getLastRow) + ':A= "","",WEEKNUM(ARRAYFORMULA(A' + (i+getLastRow) + ':A)))');
      }
    }
    file.setTrashed(true);
  }
};
```

Thank you

Comment: would you like to share with us the full script you are using? It looks like you need to optimize the process more. Make the script faster or the source spreadsheet file lighter. See some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302086/google-spreadsheet-script-problem-error-service-times-out-apps-script).

Comment: Please put that code in the question itself by editing it.

Comment: Does this behavior occur only with a certain (particularly big) csv file? This error can mean that you perform asynchroneous requests in parallel. Can be solved by adding [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) inside the for loop. Also, use [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) instead of multiple `setValue()` requests to make your code more [efficient](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

Comment: Thx Ziganotscka for the comments. It seems that the root cause of the issue was spreadsheet limitation. I created a new spreadsheet and seems to working fine. Thank you anyway for the suggested improvements.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisGeormas, could you help me finding that limitation? I am having the exact same issue and I can benefit from your experience

Answer (score 4):

This issue started to appear also in my macros.

First workaround that worked for me but just for few weeks was copying the macro on a new appScript file (same Spreadsheet) and deleting the previous one.

Second workaround that is still working after few months is adding
SpreadsheetApp.flush() before and after the line where the error appeared:

`SpreadsheetApp.flush();`
`// Line with the error`
`SpreadsheetApp.flush();`

Comment: In my case, the error now happens at like `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`

Comment: @BingLi224 Same `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is the one causing the problems